# ExtractToFile throwing Access Denied Error?

Tags: c#, security, iis

First of all, I clear that I am using ASP.NET 4.5 with DefaultAppPool(integrated 4.0). I have also configured Anonymous Access to DefaultAppPool user.  I have given all access to DefaultAppPool. `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` method give me the same user. But when the following line runs it gives me `Access to the path 'XXXX' is denied.` exception. Then for testing purpose, I have given all rights to `EveryOne` user but still getting the same error. Here is the line of code. Note the trus

```
        using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipStream))
        {
            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry file in archive.Entries)
            {
                file.ExtractToFile(location,true);
            }
        }
```

Here is the StackTrace,

```
[UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'XXX' is denied.]
   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +10793558
   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) +1352
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) +65
   System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions.ExtractToFile(ZipArchiveEntry source, String destinationFileName, Boolean overwrite) +96
   XX.XX.XX.ExtractZipFile(Stream zipStream, String location) in XX.cs:44
   XX.XX.XX.XX.XX.XX.ExtractZipFile(Stream zipStream, String location) in XXX.cs:17
```

Comment: Does the DefaultAppPool user have access (read/write permission) to the path in question?

Comment: @Tim, Yes Full Control. Also I have given Full Control to Everyone user.

Comment: Does the DefaultAppPool user have Execute/Traverse access on all the folders in the path?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, See the edit. I have given all access.

Comment: .NET exception in this case giving me the wrong exception. The problem was that I was just passing location(folder location without file name). Anyone just write this as answer then I will make it as answer. So, it will help-full for others as well.

Comment: @user960567 - you can post the answer and accept it yourself after a waiting period.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

.NET framework in this case giving me the wrong exception. The problem was that, I was just passing location(folder location without file name). So after including complete path, this works.

Comment: This was super helpful as I did the same thing.

Comment: I wanted to vote up, but it appeared I already voted a year ago!